# .profile not getting sourced after update

Tags: updates, nodejs, .profile

I have recently update my Ubuntu. After update I am unable to use `nvm` command(node version manager) which is configured using following code

~/.profile

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/saurabh/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Comment: If you source the script manually by running `. ~/.profile`, does it work then?

Comment: @ByteCommander Yeah Its working but as I close my terminal and then open other terminal then its not working.

Comment: Do you have a `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` file?